# MySQl multivalued and in query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables
device_part:

| device_id | part_id | software_version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jdvjdksfks | 1 | v1 |
| jdvjdksfks | 2 | v2 |
| peirizkdsf | 1 | v1 |
| peirizkdsf | 2 | v3 |

strategy_part:

| strategy_id | part_id | source_version | target_version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | v1 | v3 |
| 1 | 1 | v2 | v3 |
| 1 | 2 | v2 | v3 |
| 2 | 3 | v1 | v2 |

How can I write a sql query all device_id when strategy_id=1, part_id all match and device_part.software_version in strategy_part.source_version

I don't know how write the SQL

I attempt write the SQL:

```sql
SELECT distinct di.device_id
FROM device_part dp
JOIN strategy_part sp on dp.part_id = sp.part_id AND dp.software_version in
(SELECT source_version FROM strategy_part WHERE part_id=sp.part_id)
WHERE sp.strategy_id=1;
```

But the result only one part also match the version relation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT device_id
FROM device_part
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM strategy_part
    WHERE strategy_part.strategy_id = 1
    AND device_part.part_id = strategy_part.part_id
    AND device_part.software_version = strategy_part.source_version
)
```

Explanation:
We use an EXISTS subquery to find all rows in strategy_part where:

- strategy_id = 1
- part_id matches device_part.part_id
- source_version matches device_part.software_version

For each such row found in the subquery, the EXISTS condition will be true, so we select the device_id from device_part.
This has the effect of finding all device_id where the part info matches a row in strategy_part with the given strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this is correct, but incomplete, I think of the SQL:

```
SELECT device_id
FROM device_part
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM strategy_part
    WHERE strategy_part.strategy_id = 2
    AND device_part.part_id = strategy_part.part_id
    AND device_part.software_version = strategy_part.source_version
)
GROUP BY device_id HAVING count(device_id)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT part_id) FROM strategy_part WHERE strategy_id = 2);
```

Can match all part_id and version, That solved my problem